# Amazon Pinpoint vs SNS vs ADM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint

I have a use case where i want to send a notification to user on an Amazon fire tablet App and upon tapping on the Notification I show him the features of App.

I want to schedule this Notification from cloud. I saw that we have two services Amazon pinpoint and SNS in doing so. But lot of their features seems overlapping.
And I also know about Amazon Device messaging which is a service to push Notification.

which service is more suitable here and why ?

They all sound confusing to me. Anyone who can keep them in simple words would help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Amazon SNS and Amazon Pinpoint, supports sending push notification to Amazon devices (e.g Amazon fire tablet) through ADM (Amazon Device Messaging).

The major difference between Amazon SNS & Amazon Pinpoint is that : with Amazon SNS you have to set up your application to manage each message's audience, content, and delivery schedule. On the other hand, with Amazon Pinpoint you do not have to code these features, most of them are already built in.  With Amazon Pinpoint, you can collect data about your app usage, create highly-targeted segments and send full campaigns(either immediate or scheduled) plus many more features.